# How to center iCarousel view

Tags: iphone, ios, icarousel

I have 6 button that i want to animate using iCarousel, the code like this

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
if (button == nil)
{
    self.icon = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"icon-02.png",@"icon-03.png",@"icon-04.png",@"icon-05.png",@"icon-06.png",@"icon-07.png",nil];


    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[icon objectAtIndex:index]];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 130.0f, 130.0f);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}



return button;
}
```

But the button is not in the center, does anyone now hot to make the carousel in centre, i already resize the uiview but still not working.
thanks...

Comment: Hey Dave try to adjust the UIView which contains the iCarousal thru the xib file , increase or decrease its width/height and the carousal will be centered eventually .... try this...

Comment: @Gill i think he already mentioned this in the last line of his question.

Comment: @Robin yep but i hav implemented the same thing and it takes some hit and trial to put it in the center ...

Comment: @Gill, thanks for the heads up, let me try again. Actually I was hoping if its in coding.

Comment: In my case, I'd forgotten to set up auto resize or auto layout constraints, so the view was ever so slightly going off the edge.

Answer (score 3):

The carousel and carousel items should be centred by default (they are in the example projects included with iCarousel, which aren't doing anything special). There's no need to tweak the position of the carousel in your nib (unless it isn't centered obviously). If this isn't working as intended, you may have found a bug - can you raise an issue on the project's github page?

Unrelated: the button recycling logic you have there is totally wrong and only works by coincidence. Amongst other things you are re-creating your icons array 6 times.

The correct way to create your buttons is like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set up icons array
     self.icon = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"icon-02.png",@"icon-03.png",@"icon-04.png",@"icon-05.png",@"icon-06.png",@"icon-07.png",nil];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
    if (button == nil)
    {
        //*************************************************
        //do setup that is the same for every button here
        //*************************************************

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 130.0f, 130.0f);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
        //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    //*************************************************
    //do setup that is different depending on index here
    //*************************************************

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[icon objectAtIndex:index]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return button;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the response. yes, turns out I have to tweak the position in nib. One other thing, how you define the carousel to be vertical/horizontal only? I saw in options demo is this correct?
    carousel.vertical = !carousel.vertical;

Comment: just set the carousel.vertical property to YES if you want it vertical, otherwise set it to NO (which is the default).

Comment: But seriously, you need to fix your if (button == nil) ... logic. There is an explanation about how to use it correctly in the basic iPhone example.

Comment: Hi Nick, turns out my button is still move to up after i click it not in the right side, just like i wanted. is there something missing?

Comment: Yes, as I've now mentioned several times, the logic in your viewForItemAtIndex is completely wrong. Hang on and I'll add an answer that explains how to do it properly.

Comment: thanks nick, i try first, will let you know the result..thanks again..!